# How to extract Twitter follower number using XLM & spreadsheets

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, spreadsheet, xlm

I want to get Twitter follower numbers on a google spreadsheet.

I used below line code and the result was `N/A`

`=importXML("https://twitter.com/elonmusk","//a[@href='/elonmusk/followers']/span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0'")`

The HTML code is

```
<a href="/elonmusk/followers" dir="auto" role="link" class="css-4rbku5 css-18t94o4 css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-1loqt21 r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-18jsvk2 r-poiln3 r-b88u0q r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">54.8M</span></span> 
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-m0bqgq r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">
<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Followers</span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a closer look at the span nodes.  The span you are trying to target is actually nested within the prior span, it is not a sibling.  Try changing this:

```
//a[@href='/elonmusk/followers']/span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0']
```

to something like the following (note /span/span instead of /span to reflect the actual hierarchy (a/span/span):

```
//a[@href='/elonmusk/followers']/span/span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0']
```

or the following (note //span instead of /span) if you don't care about the hierarchy between the a and target span nodes:

```
//a[@href='/elonmusk/followers']//span[@class='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0']
```